# what's differences between when defining a hook in .theme vs .module in drupal 8

Tags: drupal

I am new in Drupal 8. And I have a confusion is : "what's differences between when defining a hook in .theme vs .module in drupal 8" ? I tried to define a hook in both of .theme and .module and result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

theme priority higher then module

Comment: Thank you for your response, anything more?

Comment: And just one more question: we can put a hook in .theme or .module?

Comment: Functional /logical should be in .module and design/theme related should be in. let say just want to change wrapper div html tag , then it should be in   .theme

Comment: Thanks @sunil is there any case a hook just works in .module or .theme?